# How to get id in svg using imageOverlay in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, svg

Is possible or not, when click at certain area in file svg it will return id.
sample id in file svg[image]

sample in jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/wanaideed/uxko5Lch/

Comment: Please do not include code as image but rather use the code tags and include it into the body of the question.

Comment: @Kersten you can view from detail svg file in my jsfiddle. Next time I not include image. Sorry.

Comment: It would be much better if you [edit] your question to address the issue this time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go about this is to load the SVG as an [HTML object](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp), rather than a Leaflet L.ImageOverlay.

The problem is that leaflet will convert the SVG to an object that you can no longer use SVG methods.

This code shows how to load your SVG as an object (I downloaded the SVG and saved it as a file from [here](https://svgshare.com/i/4x_.svg)), and to add the event of showing country names upon clicking on each polygon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <object data="sample.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
         id="map" width="2100" height="1900"></object>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("map");
            a.addEventListener("load",function(){

                // get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
                // get the inner element by id
                var el = svgDoc.getElementsByClassName("land");

                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

                (function () {
                    var countryName=el[i].getAttribute('title');
                    el[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function() { alert(countryName); }, false);
                }()); 
                }
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```